# Get all the conversations of a user

Tags: botframework

(New to Microsoft Bot Framework) Is there a way in which I can find all the existing conversations of a user? I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework (SDK4) to make a chat bot.

Requirement: I want to list all the conversations a user has had till now.

Comment: Conversations are only stored for up to 24 hours on the ABS. If you are wanting to access conversations for longer, you need to implement one the storage options (CosmosDb, blob, etc.) to capture and retain that data. You can read the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript.

Comment: Or, do you mean you have the data but aren't sure what code to use to access it?

Comment: @StevenKanberg: I have stored the transcripts in a blobstore. But am not sure if bot framework has an inbuilt method exposed to get all the conversations in which a user is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot Framework, at this time, doesn't have a way of ingesting all past conversations from a transcript or store.

However, there are a couple options for how you can capture user conversations so you don't have to rely on a complete transcript of a conversation.

The first option is to implement middleware that logs the activity or elements of the activity you want. What you choose to capture and what you choose to do with it is up to you. In the following code, I am logging in the console all user responses and all bot activity that isn't a typing event or an endOfConversation event. You would replace the console.log() calls with your custom code that would store the data. Just keep in mind, that whatever call you make here would happen on every user / bot activity. If you're looking to make API calls, consider storing the data in an object and saving it when the 'endOfConversation' is returned (or something similar).

```js
adapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
    // turnContext.(async (ctx, activities, next) => {
    //     activities.filter(a => a.type === 'message').forEach(a => console.log('From user: ', a));
    // });
    const userActivity = turnContext.activity;
    if (userActivity.from.role === 'user' && turnContext.activity.text.length > 0) {
        console.log('From user: ', userActivity);
    }

    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) => {
        await nextSend();

        activities.filter(a => a.type !== 'typing' && a.type !== 'endOfConversation').forEach(a => console.log('From bot: ', a));
    });
    await next();
});
```

The second option is to model your bot after the [logger](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/25.logger) / [transcript-logger](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/26.transcript-logger) samples from the Botbuilder-Samples repo. You can modify the customLogger.js file to match your needs and output to a store.

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi @Steven Kanberg, I have used option 2 for now and storing it in a blob store, but the retrieval is very slow and not in the correct order (it provides the earliest transcripts first instead of the latest ones), which causes a lot of dealy in the response.

Comment: @nbirla, Consider using something other blob storage as there are indications (nothing official) that the BotFramework is leaning away from supporting blob storage. It doesn't scale well nor is overly configurable in this environment. Instead, consider CosmosDB (a pricier option but is supported out-of-the-box) or implement a method of your own. There is an user example [here](https://github.com/proarchgithub/msbotframework-mongo-middlelayer) for v3 that demos using Mongo. There should be enough information there for you to implement for v4.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Kanberg, that sounds fair.